# Dangers of Unsecured Wireless Networks

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it dangerous to use an unsecured wireless connection? Can my username and password be seen if I transmit them on an open connection, or are they encrypted on the client side before being sent to the server? Can any of my local files be affected or only transmitted data?

Comment: If you're using public WiFi or using your home wireless, it's safe to assume that data is secure if you're using HTTP**S**.  The problem is that there are a lot of sites using standard HTTP, and when it's unencrypted like that, there isn't any assurance that the data you're getting is what the sender intended; that's referred to as a MITM attack.  If someone embeds content into that request and you happen to be vulnerable to what they're trying to exploit, they can certainly affect your local files (e.g. encrypt your HDD and demand a ransom).

Comment: Is an up to date, modern OS easily exploited in an MITM attack or is this airing on the side of caution? Would my local anti-malware be likely to catch / defend against it?

Comment: Not entirely, someone could easily embed a malicious iframe into your HTTP connection and use an encrypted payload to get around.  Check out [this post on Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44345/techniques-for-anti-virus-evasion).  And on that note, this question would net a **MUCH** better answer over there.

Answer (score 2):

Anybody with an antenna can receive and decode wifi packets - it's not going to prevent the wifi router from also receiving the packets - and you would never know. Such is "broadcast".

As to whether your userid and password would be seen, that depends on how they are passed to the remote server. For an HTTP connection using Basic authentication, the password is sent in clear text so anybody capturing your wifi packets would be able to replay the stream and find see it. An HTTPS connection will first negotiate a secure connection with SSL or TLS in order to prevent such snooping and then even Basic authentication cannot be seen inside of it by the snooper.

As for your local files, the person would first have to gain access to your computer, to log into it, and run programmes on it to access the files on your hard drive. Simply having an unsecured wifi will not directly allow that, nor will having a secured wifi prevent it, such as when the cracker's computer is on the same access point as you like at a café with wifi that you need to use the weekly password to connect.

Comment: Let's say I log into facebook over an open connection. Are all my activities protected while I am using the site or does the SSL / TLS protection only apply for user creds? Can they see what I send in messages to my friends?

Comment: The SSL/TLS connection of HTTPS is JUST a wrapper around a regular HTTP request. First the SSL/TLS connection is negotiated, then a regular HTTP request is sent inside that. User credentials are not some separate, distinct transaction with the webserver - the only way you can communicate with it is by making HTTP(S) requests. As long as the interaction is HTTPS, the snooper cannot see anything inside it, whatever data it may be. Facebook, specifically, redirects any plain HTTP connection to HTTPS